# Problem with if statements, containing token from strtok in C

Tags: c, if-statement, strtok

Here's the task:
1)07/21/2003
2)July 21, 2003

Write a program that reads a date in the first format and prints it in the second format.

I am supposed to use string methods, especially **strtok**.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char date[20];
    char month[20];
    char day[20];
    char year[20];
    char *token;
    char sep[1] = "/";

    printf("Enter the date (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
    gets(date);

    token = strtok(date, sep);

    if (token == "01")
    {
        strcpy(month, "Januray");
    }

    else if (token == "02")
    {
        strcpy(month, "February");
    }

    //continuing in this way
   
    }

    else if (token == "11")
    {
        strcpy(month, "November");
    }

    else
    {
        strcpy(month, "December");
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    strcpy(day, token);

    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    strcpy(year, token);

    printf("%s %s, %s", month, day, year);
}
```

The problem is that the month part always gives December, which means if statements do not work.

Comment: What exactly *is* the value of that token?

Comment: In C (please tag) I don't think you can compare string values with ==

Comment: "I am supposed to use string methods". One of those is `strcmp`, check what it does.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing same as the string, I tested it with strcmp method and it returned the value 0

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I changed double equation to single equation, now it gives only January.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Checked and it returned 0, which means they have same value.

Comment: Checked what exactly? where? "I changed double equation to single equation" That's not what you are supposed to do. Check what `strcmp` does again.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. that comment was not for you, my friend

Comment: `char sep[1] = "/";` does not create a C string, because there's no room for the NUL terminator that every string must have. Therefore, you cannot pass `sep` to `strtok`. Furthermore, there's no reason for `sep`. You can just pass the string to `strtok` directly, e.g. `token = strtok(date, "/");`

Comment: However, I did what you just said and it worked. Just replaced if statements in this way:

Comment: if (strcmp(token, "01") == 0)
    {
        strcpy(month, "Januray");
    }

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3386109 I understood the mistake, but I don't know why, the code works anyway. Nevertheless, I changed sep[1] = "/" to sep[2] = "/".

Comment: Yup, that's the problem with running past the end of an array. Sometimes things appear to work, when in fact there's a latent bug, that will come to the surface at the most inconvenient time. Like when you try to demonstrate the code to your professor.

Comment: A single = is not a comparison but an assignment, a == does reference equality in the case of strings, not value equality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

writing like this

```
if (token == "01")
```

does not do what you think it does, `token` points to the start of the string (date), so you are comparing two addresses with each other, instead to compare the actual string contents use strcmp().

```
if (strcmp(token,"01") == 0)
```

but the above method is a bit error prone, what if the user enters "1" instead? So a better way would be to convert it to an integer:

```
char* tokenend = NULL;
int mon = strtol(token, &tokenend, 10);
```

then you can use `mon` in a switch which makes the code a little bit less verbose.

```
switch(mon) {
  case 1:
    strcpy(month,"January");
    break;
    ...
  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid month entered %s", token);
    break;
}
```

note also that `strtok` changes the contents of `date` so the original date is no more. if you want to keep the original string then you need to store is separately.

In general you should use `fgets` instead of `gets` when reading a string from the keyboard since `gets` does not limit the number of characters it can read

```
if (fgets(date, sizeof(date), stdin) != NULL)
{
  // and remove the \n
  char* p = strchr(date,'\n');
  if (p != NULL) *p  = '\0';
}
```

Comment: The code is less verbose still if instead of a big `switch` statement one uses an array: `const char* months = {"January", "February", ...};`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. you probably meant `char* months[]` but yes, the point being that evaluating the month number would make it a bit less error prone.